# replace support in qualitative influence line analysis

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

In i ) I was told that for the pinned support , we can assume to replace it with a roller , while for the cantilever , we can assume it to be supported by double roller .

For the cantilever , why we cant replace it with roller instead of double roller ? What 's the difference between double and single roller ?

In iv ) I was told that we can use roller guide , so from the figure , it's single roller , right ? So , IMO , the ii) was wrong , for the cantilever , we should always use single roller[image: 22]

[image: 3232]

Comment: I've just posted an answer to [your other recent question](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13388/qualitative-influence-line-of-pinned-support). This question looks to be along similar lines; the answer to the other question may also apply here.

Comment: Ok, @AndyT , i understand that the statement In order to draw the deflected shape properly, the capacity of the beam to resist the applied function must be removed so the beam can deflect when the function is applied.                                                                                                     For the cantilever , why we cant replace it with roller instead of double roller ? What 's the difference between double and single roller ?

Comment: continuous from previous comment , In iv ) I was told that we can use roller guide , so from the figure , it's single roller , right ? So , IMO , the ii) was wrong , for the cantilever , we should always use single roller

Comment: Why we need to use double roller for case iv ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your quote/picture:

> If the support A is cantilever type, a double roller guide must be used at A **since this type of support will then transmit both a moment M<sub>A</sub> at the fixed support** and axial load, R<sub>Ax</sub> but will not transmit R<sub>Ay</sub>.

In other words, we want the influence for the vertical reaction, so we release the vertical support degree of freedom only, *and leave the other supported degrees of freedom alone*.

As far as iv) goes, I can see three rollers in the picture. This is analogous to a "double roller": it will transmit axial load and moment but not shear load.

Comment: Why double roller guide cant transmit vertical shear load  ? We can see that the double roller enable the beam to move upwards and downwards , right ?P/s : I agree that in the iv) case , the roller guide will prevent the segment of beam from deflect / moving , because it's fixed support on the left end

Comment: @kelvinmacks - Yes, the double roller enables the beam to move upwards and downwards. How could vertical shear be transmitted across that interface? Shear is a force resisting two adjacent "faces" moving relative to one another.

Comment: actually  what  is  the  meaning  of  the the  support  will  not  transmit  Ray ?  It  means  the  support  will  not  transmit  vertical  shear ?  What's  the  meaning  of  not  transmit  vertical  shear ?

Comment: **RAy** is the **R**eaction at **A** in the **y** direction. With a beam on only one side, the reaction would be equal to the shear. "Transmit vertical shear" means that... vertical shear will be transmitted (passed/carried) from one side to the other (or in this case, from the beam into the support). If you still don't understand what "transmit vertical shear" means then you really need to go back to the beginning of your engineering course and stop trying to understand more advanced topics like influence lines.

Comment: by saying that  "Transmit vertical shear" means that... vertical shear will be transmitted (passed/carried) from one side to the other (or in this case, from the beam into the support).                                                            Do you mean that the shear force is constant throughout the whole beam ( from fixed end to free end )? In the notes , we could see that the influence line is a straight line constant throughout the beam , so the beam is said to be able to transmit vertical shear , right ?

Comment: Every time I am talking about whether or not vertical shear is transmitted, I'm talking about at the place under consideration. For the reaction at the cantilever support (ii), it is about whether shear can be transmitted from the beam to the support: when you introduce the roller no shear can be transmitted *across that joint*. For part way along the beam (iv) it is about whether shear can be transmitted from the right of point B to the left of point B: when you introduce the roller no shear can be transmitted *across that joint*.

Comment: Anywhere that we haven't introduced a roller/joint the shear can be transmitted as it is in a normal beam.

Comment: you  say that for both cases , the roller cant transmit the vertical shear , but in case ii ) , we could see that the influence line for Ray is a straight line ( This means the vertical shear is transmitted throughout the beam , am i right ) ? For case iv) , we also see that although there's no vertical shear on the left part of the applied force , but on the right , we could see that it's straight line from the B to the cantilever end , this means the vertical shear is transmitted , right ?

Comment: 1. The influence line is the deflected shape, not the shear force diagram. 2. For case (ii) vertical shear can be transmitted throughout the beam **except it can't be transmitted from the beam to the support**. For case (iv) shear can be transmitted from the end of the beam, as far as B, **but it can't be transmitted over the roller at B**. It can then be transmitted anywhere from the left of B through the beam to the support at A. Would you like me to point out where I've already explained this point no2, or are you now able to read my previous comments and understand?

Comment: Sorry , @AndyT , i still cant understand why the vertical shear transmitted from the beam to the roller ... Perhaps , i missed ou something important ? Can you explain further ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks - Your lack of forming grammatical sentences makes it very difficult to understand what you are asking. "i still cant understand why the vertical shear transmitted from the beam to the roller" is not grammatical. That said, if you still can't understand what I've been saying, then you appear to be lacking a basic understanding of either a) shear, or b) what a roller joint is.